# Codesigning with timestamp doesnt work

Tags: java, ssl, jar, certificate, code-signing

I have a jar which is was signed with a valid( not expired) cert last year and it was timestamp too. This year the cert has expired and the console gives a warning " your jar is signed with a non-valid or expired cert. Ideally this warning should not be there since it was timestamp when the cert was valid.
Could anyone suggest how can i see the timestamp( if it had fail when it was timstamping the jar) or see the root cause of it.

Comment: `jarsigner -verify -verbose -certs <your.jar>` : You will see _entry was signed on ..._

Comment: Also, you can check if the timestamping certificate has not expired. First, open your .jar with an archive manager like 7-Zip and extract the META-INF\<sthing>.RSA file. Second, run `openssl asn1parse -in <sthing.RSA> -inform DER -i` and check the UTCTime fields for the timestamping certificate (near the end of the output). There are two field, first is _notBefore_, second is _notAfter_. They are formatted as follow : YYmmddhhmmss.

Comment: in my jarsigner command i use thawte timestamp server but in the <sthng>.RSA file it shows tsa of verisign( that is verisign.com/rpa) and thawte ( geotrust ) which is actually being used? and if the UTCTime shows from 78 to 10( for YY) will java undersatnd that its 1978 and 2010? actually my codesigned and timestamped .jar is throwing cert expired error, which should not come as i m using timestamp.

Comment: Not Sir but timestamp is valid as long as timestamping certificate is valid. Would you mind posting the .RSA file somewhere ?

Comment: If timestamping works till cert is valid then what is the use of timestamping. AFAIK timestamping is used for intergrity and to validate the binary even if the cert is expired.I have read in a post that validation-of-timestamp-depending-on-cert-expiry depends on some flags in certificate used for code signing, Is it like that? Not sure if i should share <sthng>.RSA publicly.

Comment: Let's quote RFC 3161 (Timestamping) : _The TSA signing key MUST be of a sufficient length to allow for a sufficiently long lifetime.  Even if this is done, the key will have a finite lifetime.  Thus, any token signed by the TSA SHOULD be time-stamped again [...] at a later date to renew the trust that exists in the TSA's signature._

Comment: Then, about the <sthing>.RSA: I can assure you (but you may verify if you don't trust me) that there is no private information contained in this file. You'll only find : code-signing cert + trust chain, timestamping cert (+ trust chain), signature, signed timestamp token. The only relevant part will be everything under the _":id-smime-aa-timeStampToken"_ line

Comment: there nothing under :id-smime-aa-timeStampToken and :pkcs7-signedData section :(

Comment: What happened when you ran `jarsigner -verify -verbose -certs <your.jar>` ? Did you see _"entry was signed on"_ ?

Comment: And answering your question _"If timestamping works till cert is valid then what is the use of timestamping ?"_ : codesigning ensures your JAR is valid until the **codesigning** cert expires. Timestamping allows extending this period until the **timestamping** cert expires. For example, your codesigning cert may be valid 3 years, but timestamping it with GlobalSign TSA (renewed in 2015-02) will allow execution until 2026, when the TSA certificate expires.

Comment: Yes i see "entry was signed on 15-03-15" the signing cert was valid at that time at the end it also generate some warnings like                                          s = signature was verified
 m = entry is listed in manifest
 k = at least one certificate was found in keystore
 i = at least one certificate was found in identity scope

jar verified.

warning:
this jar contains entries whose signer certificate has expired.

Comment: Are we supposed to have "Geotrust timestamp signer 1" cert while timestamping the signed jar or while verifying the timestamp. I have "Thawte timestamp CA" cert in JRE cert store but i dont have cert for "Geotrust timestamp signer 1".

Comment: Does timestamping work if jar is executed through a JNLP? in case of JNLP it will be invoked by jws.